Amazon ses API V2 via postman gives "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
I am trying to hit amazon ses api v2 via postman, i have to integrate into influxdb directly so sdk is not an option. I am receiving 200 ok with com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException and finding it hard to get the logs. I think there is something i am doing wrong in how i am framing the request.Kindly help

{
"Content": {
"Simple": {
"Body": {
"Html": {
"Charset": "UTF-8",
"Data": "There have been some critical statuses."
}
},
"Subject": {
"Charset": "UTF-8",
"Data": "InfluxDB critical alert"
}
}
},
"FromEmailAddress": "test@gmail.com",
"Destination": {
"ToAddresses": [
"test@gmail.com"
]
}
}
